# Variable naming conventions with respect to their contents

Tags: php, resources, file, naming-conventions, handle

I understand there's gazillions of questions pertaining to conventions. I couldn't find much, however, regarding some specifics that have always plagued me in my coding.

**It comes down to filesystem and device representations, whether a handle/resource or path; what conventions are often followed to appropriately name variables containing such values/data?**

More specifically I mean:

- `/path/to/resource/` **A directory path** (`$dirpath`)
- *`(handle)`* **A file handle/resource** (`$filehandle`)
- `filename.php` **A file name** (`$filename`)
- `/path/to/resource/filename.php` **A file path** (`$filepath`)

If any of these are incorrect, please advise; concern over this may seem asinine, however I want to secure the understanding for myself, not to mention future colleagues.

Any directions to references/complete lists, or suggestions from your personal experience are more than welcome.

(*marked it as PHP in case there are any language specific conventions I should know*)

Comment: You can name variables whatever you want. `$path`, `$file`, `$theFile`, `$handle`, `$pointer`... they all work and make sense. Since PHP is typeless you probably won't ever use prefixes. Just don't use nonsensical variables like `$jkQ` unless it's `$i` in a `for` loop or something else that's very obvious. Questions about naming conventions are subjective.

Comment: **Thanks minitech**; I'm quite content with the naming conventions as prescribed by Zend, however this minor caveat has been the source of much deliberation on my behalf. I'm just curious to know what conventions tenured developers have followed in the past.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: *`what conventions are often followed to appropriately name variables containing such values/data?`*

Comment: @TomcatExodus: If you have a filename, write `$filename`. If you have a filepath, write `$filepath`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I suppose not; perhaps I need a refresh on what differentiates as path from a filename. Close understood.

Comment: I could debate over filename. I usually use filename for no extension part. Meaning: $filename = 'filename'; On filename.php i would rather go as basename. As well as for directory basename. Paths are same for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using pretty standard variable names there, so I don't think any php programmer would mistake those for something else.

Comment: **Thanks Rob Bailey**; I've never thought that I would baffle anyone with the choices I've made, but I was curious about the *path/name* use interchangeability. I always use *path* under circumstances where the containing string suggests directory tree traversal, regardless of the target being a file or directory. Wanted to know if others share this idiom.

Comment: In Unix-like operating systems, *everything* is a file, whether it is a device, a directory, or a text file. Different operations can be performed on text files vs. directories, of course, but the filesystem still views them substantially the same. IMHO, you shouldn't need to fret over when to use 'path' in your PHP variable name, regardless of whether you are specifying a directory or a file.